# Access Another Machine within a Hotel's Protected Network

Tags: networking, remote

I'm at a hotel right now and I need to do some dev with a Linux machine and a Windows machine. I need to access a web app that's running on the Linux box from the Windows for browser testing.

While both computers are on the same network (local IP addresses of 192.168.6.47 and 192.168.6.6 respectively), they can't see each other. All pings die, and attempting to access the app results in a 404 error. I assume certain protections on the network are preventing the machines from communicating.

Is there any clever way to get the two machines to chat? I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: Crossover cable?

Comment: A brilliantly simple solution for tomorrow. I doubt I can find one right now (it's 11PM here).

Comment: Build linux drives to make the NIC in the linux box act as the crossover?

Comment: Create an ad-hoc network instead of using the hotel network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up a hamachi vpn between the two machines.  Sounds the AP's are running in isolation mode, so you may have better luck routing out and then back in if you can't get the cable or go to a 24 hour store like wal mart and get a switch and cabling.
win client
https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/download.aspx

linux client
https://secure.logmein.com/labs/